# Add dependencies in Eclipse using Gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I'm using the Gradle IDE plugin for Eclipse and I've created a custom task in my build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['tests']
    }
}

dependencies {
    unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/debug")
    unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    unitTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.1'
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2' 
}

configurations {
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    description = "run unit tests"
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}

build.dependsOn unitTest
```

The problem is that the dependencies I've referenced are not added in Eclipse and I get the error that `import org.junit.Test;`,  `import org.robolectric.Robolectric;` and so on, can't be resolved. I've tried right clicking on the project -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Add this to the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
eclipse {
    classpath {    
        plusConfigurations += configurations.unitTestCompile
      }
}
```

and then right-click on project -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies.